# UWP Memory Leak by calling ServiceReference (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a Problem:

1. I created a default ServiceReference

   ```
   [OperationContract]
   string GetData(int value);
   ```

   Implementation:

   `public string GetData(int value)
    {
       return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }`
2. Add ServiceReference into a new UWP Project
   ([Add Reference Pic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS6Sn.png))
3. In the UWP Main Constructor I Call:

   `void Test()
           {
               ServiceReference.Service1Client h = new ServiceReference.Service1Client();
               for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
               {
                   var u = h.GetDataAsync(5);
               }
           }`

   Or:

   `async void Test()
    {
      ServiceReference.Service1Client h = new ServiceReference.Service1Client();
      for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
      {
        var u = await h.GetDataAsync(5);
       }
     }`
4. The Problem:
   The WCF Service works. The UWP-App works. But the process memory decreases never.
   [Memory Pic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU8fI.png)
   The garbage collector do nothing.

   When I call:

   `GC.Collect(2);
   GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();`

   It Change "Nothing" (does not rise as much). But the process memory decreases never.

   On devices with low memory the App will crash when the Memory is full.(raspberry pi 2 / 3).

   What am I doing wrong.

Raspberry pi 2 / 3 Scenario: A App is calling a ServiceReference in a daily loop. THe App is Running the whole year. Sometime the app will Crash because the Memory is full.

Comment: You posted just a part of your code but, isn't missing the dispose or put your client inside a using block?

Comment: The ServiceReference has no dispose function. Only IDisposable Objects can be use in a Using-Block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1)set "ServiceReference.Service1Client h = new ServiceReference.Service1Client();"
to Global parameter

or
(2)h.Dispose() in the end

Comment: The Global-Option work.  
The ServiceReference has no dispose function.